# Karma: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I extend global Object:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'getRecursive', {writable: false, value: function(keyChain){
    var keys = keyChain.split('.');

    if(keys.length > 1){
      var currentKey = keys[0];
      keys.splice(0, 1);

      return this.getRecursive.call(this[currentKey], keys.join('.'));
    }

    return this[keys[0]];
  }});
```

and when I run tests I have: `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.` at `node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js`.

When I change `writable` to `true` error disappear, why?

Function on `value` is default value of property and `writable` should allow/deny change this value, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation on [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) `writable` defines whether or not the defined property will be modifiable using an assignment operator.

> When the writable property attribute is set to false, the property is
>   said to be “non-writable”. It cannot be reassigned.

In strict mode this will lead to a `TypeError` being thrown as you mentioned.
I'm not sure on which line of `node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js` the error is thrown but you'll probably find a reassignment there which is not allowed because the `getRecursive` property is marked as non-writable.